# control which feature classes in an ArcGIS Network Dataset are "snappable" for incidents/facilities?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I'm using ArcGIS Network Analyst in conjunction with the GTFS extension to answer the question: How far is a random sampling of houses in my town from the nearest McDonald's? via transit/walking.

My problem is that the Facilities (McDonald's) and Incidents (residential buildings) are being located along the Transit Lines feature class in my Network Dataset; then when I go to solve the analysis, any features that get located along a transit line aren't evaluated because the "network element is not traversable". Is there a way I can restrict which feature classes in the Network Dataset can be used to locate facilities/incidents? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Finding Network Locations" section under Layer Properties -> Network Locations, there is a "Snap To:" field. I'm assuming the Transit Lines feature class is currently checked, try changing it to your Streets Network Dataset feature class, that should make it traversable.